# How do you make members inaccessible to sub-derived classes?

Tags: c#, abstraction, access-modifiers

Say I have a base class like this:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
  protected void MyMethod(string myVariable)
  {
    //...
  }
}
```

Then I inherit this class in a separate assembly:

```
public abstract class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
  static readonly string MyConstantString = "Hello";
  protected void MyMethod()
  {
    MyMethod(MyConstantString);
  }
}
```

I now want to make sure that any other class that inherits from `MyDerivedClass` does not have access to the `MyBaseClass.MyMethod()` method. (To clarify, I still want to be able to call `MyDerivedClass.MyMethod()` with no parameters)

I tried using `protected internal` but that didn't work.

Update: I'm trying to do this because the application I'm working on has a bunch of separate programs that use a base class. There are 5 different "types" of programs, each performs a specific, separate function but they all have some common code that I am trying to abstract into this base class. The common code is 99% the same, differing only slightly depending on what type of program is calling it. This is why I have my base class taking a string parameter in the example which then disappears in the derived base class, as that class knows it performs role x so it tells its base class accordingly.

Comment: Do you meant that you don't want them to call it, or that you don't want them to override it?

Comment: @MatthewWatson both.

Comment: You can't stop it from being called.

Comment: You can't do that, basically. You can't make a member accessible only to a single other class.

Comment: Easy, make it `private`

Comment: Yes, why are you making `MyMethod()` protected if you don't want it to be overridden? Just make it `private` like MickyD says.

Comment: Good thing is that you most likely don't need it anyway.

Comment: [These](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx) are your only options for accessibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not quite possible. And it may be a sign that your object design might be in trouble, but that's not a question for SO.

You can try a bit more underhanded approach, though:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
  protected abstract string MyConstantString { get; }

  protected void MyMethod()
  {
    //...
  }
}

public abstract class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
  protected override sealed string MyConstantString => "Hello";
}
```

Or, more typically, just use the constructor to pass the required argument:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
  private readonly string myString;

  protected MyBaseClass(string myString)
  {
    this.myString = myString;
  }

  protected void MyMethod()
  {
    //...
  }
}

public abstract class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
  protected MyBaseClass() : base("Hello") {}
}
```

Classes derived from `MyDerivedClass` have no way to change the argument in either case, the second approach is a bit nicer from inheritance perspective (basically, the type is a closure over an argument of its ancestor type).

Comment: Using the constructor got me close enough to what I wanted. I didn't even think about constructors!

Answer (score 2):

Then I would instead of inheritance use composition in the `MyDerivedClass`. So all derived classes from this class does not know the methods from `MyBaseClass`. The class `MyBaseClass` would i make package visible so it is not possible to use it.

```
abstract class MyBaseClass
{
  void MyMethod(string myVariable)
  {
    //...
  }
}

abstract class MyDerivedClass
{
   static readonly string MyConstantString = "Hello";
   private MyBaseClass baseClass;

   MyDerivedClass(MyBaseClass baseClass) 
   {
       this.baseClass = baseClass;
   }

  protected void MyMethod()
  {
    baseClass.MyMethod(MyConstantString);
  }
}
```

The class names should be changed of course.

Comment: Delegation is probably the way to go here, correct; but if you simply write wrappers in the containing class (like you demonstrate with MyDerivedClass.MyMethod() which just calls through to MyBaseClass.MyMethod()) the whole purpose is defeated. Delegation is only a solution if the containing classes logic is more complex so that there is no simple 1:1 relation between wrapped and wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop inheriting classes from calling this method - you have made it `protected` so your intent is for it to be accessible to classes that inherit from it, whether directly, or via another sub-class.

If you want to keep the inheritance, the best you can do is to throw an error if the sub-class calls it in `MyDerivedClass`:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    protected void MyMethod(string myVariable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myVariable);
    }
}

public abstract class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
    static readonly string MyConstantString = "Hello";
    protected void MyMethod()
    {
        base.MyMethod(MyConstantString);
    }

    protected new void MyMethod(string myVariable)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not allowed");
    }
}

public class SubDerivedClass : MyDerivedClass
{
    static readonly string MyConstantString = "Hello";
    public void Foo()
    {
        MyMethod(MyConstantString);
    }
}
```

When `Foo()` is called in `SubDerivedClass`, it will call `MyMethod` in `DerivedClass`, which will throw the Exception.